# bcrypt.compare promise always returns false

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, bcrypt

I've looked through the other issues with bcrypt.compare on GitHub and none of the solutions have worked for me.  It always fails on console.log("failed 3") inside bcrypt.compare()

I've tried switching the .then() instead of using a callback with bcrypt.compare as suggested by another post but that hasn't help.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is a copy of my code and summary of versions being used:

- Node v8.12.0
- Express 4.16.0
- bcrypt 3.0.3
- jsonwebtoken 8.4.0
- mongoose 5.4.1

**Bcrypt Hash (Password Hashing)**

```
function saveUserData(req, res, next, userSignUpInfo, info){
bcrypt.hash(req.body.email, 10, (err, hash) =>{ 
if (err){   
  return res.status(500).json({
    error: err
  })
} else {
  console.log('inside test route')
  console.log('req.body.fnUserName', userSignUpInfo.fnUserName)
  const userData = new UserData({
    fnUserName : userSignUpInfo.fnUserName,
    password : hash,
    email : req.body.email,
    verify: userSignUpInfo.verify,
    createAccountDate: userSignUpInfo.createAccountDate,
    userId : userSignUpInfo.userId,
    friends: null,
    online: null
    })
  userData.save()
    .then(result => {
      console.log('result from MongoDB Cloud', result);
      saveApiData(info, userSignUpInfo, res);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log('error from MongoDB Cloud', err));
}
})
}
```

**Bcrypt Compare (Auth User)**

```
    router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    UserData.find({email: req.body.email})
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
      if(user.length < 1) {
        console.log("failed 1")
     return res.status(401).json({
      message: 'Authentication Failed'
    });
    }
    console.log('user[0].password', user[0].password)
    console.log(' user[0].password',  user[0].password)
    console.log(' req.body.password',  req.body.password)

    bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,user[0].password).then(function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("failed 1")
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: 'Authentication Failed'

      });
    }
    if (result) {
      const token = jwt.sign(
        {
        email: user[0].email,
        userId: user[0].userId
        },
        process.env.JWT_KEY,
        {
          expiresIn: "1h"  // he suggested one hour
        }
      );
      console.log("failed 2")
      return res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Authentication Successful',
        token: token
      })
    } else {
      console.log("failed 3")
      res.status(401).json({
        message: 'Authentication Failed'
      })
    }
    })
    })
     .catch(err => {
     console.log('err in login', err);
     res.status(500).json({
      error: err,
      message: 'error logging in'
    })
     })
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result` will always be undefined since promises return a single value and errors are simply thrown in the catch phrase. So basically, in your code, err will contain the actual result.
What your code should look like is the following:

```
bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,user[0].password).then((result)=>{
  if(result){
    console.log("authentication successful")
    // do stuff
  } else {
    console.log("authentication failed. Password doesn't match")
    // do other stuff
  }
})
.catch((err)=>console.error(err))
```

Comment: Great catch @omarwaleed , updated code b/c this is cleaner but I still have same issue.  Any other ideas? 

`bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password).then((result) => {
  if (result) {
   console.log("failed 2")
   return res.status(200).json({
    message: 'Authentication Successful',
   })
 } else { 
  console.log("failed 3")
  return res.status(401).json({
    message: 'Authentication Failed'
    })
  }
  })
 })
 .catch((err) => {
   console.log('err in login', err);
    res.status(500).json({
     error: err,
    message: 'error logging in'
      })
 })`

Comment: thanks man. Ok so could you please write the code you use to create the hash. I am starting to consider that the hashing of the password itself might contain some error. Please add it to the question so the formatting of the code isn't lost

Comment: I was thinking that too.  I just added the code used for hashing.  I'm new to node and I also have express validator and sessions running.  I have a feeling that may be an issue too?

Comment: you're hashing the email and not the password

Comment: no worries :) also if the problem is solved please accept the answer that best helped you out with your problem :)

Answer (score 4):

Usually, password is saved as hash in the database. Also, provide adequate length for saving hashes into database.(atleast 60 varchars). To do so,

```
schema.pre("save", function (next) {
    bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
        this.password = hash;
        next();
    });
});
```

Then, plain password is compared against the hash from database.

```
bcrypt.hash('mypassword', 10, function(err, hash) {
    if (err) { throw (err); }
    bcrypt.compare('mypassword', hash, function(err, result) {
        if (err) { throw (err); }
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't return your res.status inside the 
`else {  console.log("failed 3")`
block like you do in the failed 2 and failed 1 blocks.

Comment: Good eye but I'm still encountering the same error :(